# A Database Error Occurred in Codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.

Filename: core/Loader.php

Line Number: 346

This is working fine in local. But in live server i am getting an error like above. Please help me to resolve this issue

Here is my database.php

```
$active_group = 'default';
$active_record = TRUE;

$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['default']['username'] = 'username';
$db['default']['password'] = 'password';
$db['default']['database'] = 'dbname';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

Comment: $db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysqli';

Comment: try this, use mysqli drivers rather than mysql

Comment: Did you try connecting without codeigniter for testing purposes?

Comment: @pavan G S, is your problem solved ?

Comment: @Ganesh Aher i used $db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysqli'; still the same error

Comment: mainly this error comes because of wrong input/values given. check your username, password and dbname once.

Comment: and check that your db is linked to your dbuser.

Comment: Do you need pconnect? Try setting to FALSE

Comment: Try to remove autoinit and load it in autload.php instead

Comment: @qwerzman i done with all your mentioned things. after this also it is not working

Answer (score 0):

hi just put this code in database.php and change username,database,password.

```
$active_group = 'default';
$query_builder = TRUE;

$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['default']['username'] = 'xyz';
$db['default']['password'] = 'Z~5gvyigui7bujbc';
$db['default']['database'] = 'demo';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysqli';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

sometime this error display when credentials are wrong  make sure the username, password and host are right.